# onMouseLeave for Popover with hiderBackdrop parameter (material ui)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

```
   <Popover
       key={element.name}
       className={classes.popover}
       classes={{
         paper: classes.paper
       }}
       open={open}
       anchorEl={this.myRef.current}
       anchorOrigin={{
         vertical: 'bottom',
         horizontal: 'left'
       }}
       transformOrigin={{
         vertical: 'top',
         horizontal: 'left'
       }}
       disableRestoreFocus
       hideBackdrop
    >
```

I have this kind of popover , I want to execute `onMouseLeave` event , but it doesn't work . How can I solve it ? It happens because as I think there is not another html element out of this element , and this is a reason that it doesn't emit any action . Maybe exist solving of this issue ?

Here is the link on the doc - https://material-ui.com/utils/popover/

Comment: what are you trying to execute with onMouseLeave Event?

Answer (score 5):

Try onMouseLeave to the PaperProps={{onMouseLeave: onClose}}

Comment: All events are posted here: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html its straight forward stuff.

Comment: This worked like a charm. The problem with onMouseLeave with the popover component is that its just like a modal and has a backdrop that takes the entire screen so the mouse never leaves. Passing the props down to PaperProps makes total sense.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and their example does not help.

You need to disable the pointer events:

```
<Popover
    style={{ pointerEvents: 'none'}}
    disableRestoreFocus
    ...
>
...
```

Or even better, use the Popper component, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is like what happened to me,Let me know if it is helpful.

```
<ButtonColorCircle
      aria-owns={open ? 'color-popover' : undefined}
      aria-haspopup="true"
      onMouseEnter={handleClick}
      // onMouseLeave={handleClose}
     /> 

<Popover
       id="color-popover"
       key={element.name}
       className={classes.popover}
       PaperProps={{onMouseLeave: handleClose}}
       onExit={handleClose}
       classes={{
         paper: classes.paper
       }}
       open={open}
       anchorEl={this.myRef.current}
       anchorOrigin={{
         vertical: 'bottom',
         horizontal: 'left'
       }}
       transformOrigin={{
         vertical: 'top',
         horizontal: 'left'
       }}
       disableRestoreFocus
       hideBackdrop
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about what you are trying to execute but Material-UI Popover has onExit feature which is equivalent to onMouseLeave.

Maybe you can do something like this,

```
     <Popover
       key={element.name}
       className={classes.popover}
       classes={{
         paper: classes.paper
       }}
       open={open}
       anchorEl={this.myRef.current}
       anchorOrigin={{
         vertical: 'bottom',
         horizontal: 'left'
       }}
       transformOrigin={{
         vertical: 'top',
         horizontal: 'left'
       }}
       disableRestoreFocus
       hideBackdrop
       onExit={() => {
         PLACE YOUR CODE HERE TO EXECUTE!!!!!
       }}
     >
```

Comment: yes, I've tried it also , but I think it is only will be working in the case when Backdrop will not be hidden

Answer (score 0):

Use this props

```
slotProps={{ paper: { onMouseLeave: handleMenuMouseLeave } }}
```

Here is the full code

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Popover from "@mui/material/Popover";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";

export default function PositionedMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    console.log("open");
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    console.log("closed");
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const handleMenuMouseEnter = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    console.log("menu mouse enter");
    // setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleMenuMouseLeave = () => {
    console.log("menu mouse leave");
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        id="demo-positioned-button"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        variant="text"
        sx={{ color: "black" }}
        aria-expanded={open ? "true" : undefined}
        onMouseEnter={(e) => handleClick(e)}
      >
        Parent
      </Button>
      <Popover
        id="demo-positioned-popover"
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        onMouseEnter={handleMenuMouseEnter}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left",
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "left",
        }}
        sx={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
        slotProps={{ paper: { onMouseLeave: handleMenuMouseLeave } }}
      >
    
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Child 1</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
         Child 2
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Child 3</MenuItem>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
}
```